# How to use map on useState to return individual results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to map a useState to return text for a div. I want it to return each status data individually for the divs, but it is returning all of the statuses for the divs after the first one. Below is a screenshot that demonstrates what I mean.
[image: Visual description of my issue]

I am wondering how can I make it so that the map only returns each individual status array once instead of displaying all of them?

The useState data looks like this:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState([{}])

[
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['Started', 'Completed', 'Finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['Started', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled']
]
```

I am mapping the result to return it onto the div like this:

```
status.map((value) => {
   if (value.statuses !== undefined){
      return ( 
         value.statuses.map((inner, innerIndex) => (
            <div>
               '{inner}' {innerIndex === value.statuses.length - 1 ? 
               '' : ' to'}
            </div>
         )
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `Text:` anywhere in your code. Please show the real example

Comment: @KonradLinkowski For the 'Text:', I just wanted to show that the part after it was the text component. The real example does not have text: preceding it. If it helps, just ignore the text: part please

Comment: But your output isn't really matching what's in the code. It's impossible to debug. I don't see `to` part either

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have updated the screenshot and code to show the output better.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bogdan-zz1hbg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have problems with the correct rendering of `div` elements by mapping `useState`. I leave here the code snippet with vanilla js, but the result would be the same.

PS: also you have some mistakes here:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState([{}])

[
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['Started', 'Completed', 'Finished'],
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['Started', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled']
]
```

You forgot the curly brackets.

#### Answers:

```
status.map(item => item.statuses && <div>{item.statuses.join(" to ")}</div>)
```

Check the results:

```js
const status = [
   {id: 'abc', statuses: ['Started', 'Completed', 'Finished']},
   {id: 'def', statuses: ['Started', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled']}
]

const res = status.map(item => item.statuses && item.statuses.join(" to "))

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @langyl For your fix, I am still getting the error where multiple statuses are displayed in one div. When this occurs, the console log returns ['Started to Completed to Finished', 'Started to Blocked to Cancelled'].

Comment: @frizefries I was guided by the description and the block diagram, maybe I wrong understood you. We all know the `map` returns an array. So, let's imagine that each item in this array is the `div` element. You will help me understand you correctly if you describe INPUT data and OUTPUT data. Here is an [example](https://hackmd.io/@Iangyl/r15cewOBj).